# go get command does not provide output nor take effect

Tags: go

I have installed go on my mac

```
go version
```

output:

```
go version go1.8.1 darwin/amd64
```

AND

```
go env
```

output:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/MYUSERNAME/go/"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/np/ts5bwp_91ns22l9h751h2j8r0000gn/T/go-build124313959=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

when I ran the following go get command:

```
go get -v github.com/miku/esbulk/cmd/esbulk
```

it neither generating any output nor does anything. Just nothing happened.

## Update 1

in GOPATH/pkg folder there is darwin_amd64 folder, in darwin_amd64 folder there is

```
github.com/miku/esbulk.a
```

Comment: Have you checked what's inside your `GOPATH/pkg` / `GOPATH/github` folders?

Comment: If it does not output anything then everything worked and you installed the command.

Comment: @AndreaM16 thanks for the response, in there is github.com/miku/esbulk.a. (see my update :))

Comment: @Flimzy: `-v` does turn on output, but there is no output.

Comment: Maybe also mention that in the absence of any explicit `GOPATH` the results end up in `$HOME/go`.

Comment: I'm sure you solve that issue by now, but if that can help others, you shold check your "$GOTOOLDIR" which is where the "go get" are going to be installed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$ go help get
usage: go get [-d] [-f] [-fix] [-insecure] [-t] [-u] [build flags] [packages]

Get downloads the packages named by the import paths, along with their
dependencies. It then installs the named packages, like 'go install'.

The -u flag instructs get to use the network to update the named packages
and their dependencies.  By default, get uses the network to check out
missing packages but does not use it to look for updates to existing packages.

The -v flag enables verbose progress and debug output.

$
```

If there is nothing to do then there is nothing to report. For example, when `go get` is run for the first time it downloads and installs, after that it does nothing because there is nothing to do, unless you force an update:

```
$ go get -v github.com/aclements/perflock/cmd/perflock 
github.com/aclements/perflock (download)
github.com/aclements/perflock/internal/cpupower
github.com/aclements/perflock/cmd/perflock
$ go get -v github.com/aclements/perflock/cmd/perflock 
$ go get -v github.com/aclements/perflock/cmd/perflock 
$ go get -v -u github.com/aclements/perflock/cmd/perflock 
github.com/aclements/perflock (download)
$ go get -v -u github.com/aclements/perflock/cmd/perflock 
github.com/aclements/perflock (download)
$ go get -v github.com/aclements/perflock/cmd/perflock 
$ go get -v github.com/aclements/perflock/cmd/perflock 
$
```

Comment: Actually what I want to see is the downloading speed. Just like `git clone`, we can see the speed, so that we needn't to consider another option.

Comment: My goodness, so it is just not showing anything in the process like `git clone` does. It confuses me because I don't know if it is work or not. Thanks btw

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you solve that issue by now, but if that can help others, you shold check your "$GOTOOLDIR" which is where the "go get" are going to be installed.

Type

```
go env
```

And check that your GOTOOLDIR is the one that should be where you want the go get to be installed.

Comment: What happens if there's no binary in this folder that contains `get` in its name? Does it mean that `go get` is not available? However, `go get <sample_package>` doesn't throw any output at all, not even a "binary not found" error or alike.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `go work` enabled, you'll need to add the repo to your go work file.

From the directory you are using:

```bash
go work use .
```